# Wordpress Custom post type rewrite permalink based on custom field

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

I need to be able to rewrite the permalink of custom post type posts to:

> {post-id}.domain.com

and if {custom-field-1} of the post has a value, to:

> {custom-field-1}.domain.com

Is it possible to do it with the wp_rewrite api, or in the post registering code some how?

BTW - the (awful) way i do it now is by:

1. Adding a wild card to my domain (*.domain.com).
2. On my index file i check with php what is the url and if it is a ubdomain or not.
3. if it is i get the subdomain part ("that-part".domain.com) and check if theres a post with this value in the specific custom field in my posts or is there a post with this id and if there is then is set the $post data to that post and include the right template file for that post type.

I know it's a bad way to that. but that's the only way i know how for now, hope you will help getting to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What have you already tried? As [wp_rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) seems like the easiest solution so far.

Not sure how you'd do this for a sub-domain without the use of any .htaccess amends. However, if based on the root domain; the below [untested] solution may work:

```
function custom_rewrite() {
  if ( ! get_post_meta( 'your_key', get_the_ID() ) ) {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^' . get_the_ID(), 'index.php?post_id=' . get_the_ID() . ', 'top' );
  } else {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^' . get_post_meta( 'your_key', get_the_ID() ), 'index.php?post_id=' . get_the_ID() . ', 'top' );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite' );
```